# Construct an example of a complete metric space such that $A$ has no upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a mapping.

> I want to find an example such that $\displaystyle A=\frac{d(fx,fy)-d(x,y)}{d(x,fx)+d(y,fy)}$ has NO upper bound for some uitable $(X,d)$ and a suitable $f$.

That is, I want to construct a complete metric space $(X,d)$ and a function $f:X\to X$ such that $A\to \infty$ for some $x,y\in X$.

I've tried in various ways, but unable to construct such ! Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have in any metric space using the triangle inequality twice
$$ d(fx, fy) \leq d(fx, x) + d(x,y) + d(y, fy).$$
So $A\leq 1$.